# Verbs for "and" and "or"?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

Are there (better) verbs for "and"ing or "or"ing a bunch of clauses together?

---

#### Edit:

Can't believe I didn't think of this earlier... would "conjoin" and "disjoin" work?

Comment: Please, could you clarify the question?

Comment: @AngloSaxon: Like, I have these (boolean) clauses, so I want to AND the second one and the NOT of the third one, and OR the result with the first. Is there a better word to say that? (Not sure how else to explain it, sorry...)

Comment: I believe you have the nouns "logical conjunction" and "logical disjunction" to represent AND and OR, but it doesn't help, because you're still going to have to describe your operation using a verb like "perform".

Comment: @MilindGanjoo: Yeah, exactly.

Comment: Is this for mathematical writing, or technical documentation?

Comment: @Mitch: The first.

Comment: Then you might also want to ask at mathematics.SE.

Comment: The question is very vague, there's no way I can give a concise answer without understanding the context of the writing better.  I could tell you how to express the verbs AND and OR, but what you're asking might be how to express the logic in a less formal way, or how to make a non technical person understand what you mean, which would produce different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'And'ing and 'or'ing are somewhat informal because of how they 'verbify' the conjunctions.

'Conjunction' and disjunction' are the nouns describing such clauses (and note that 'conjunctino' does double duty as the general term for the combining word and also for the 'and'-like word.

That is in some sense formally and logically correct, but making a verb out of these doesn't sound like what you want.

> Conjoin clause A to clause B

would not come across as 'make the phrase A and B'. It sounds more like 'connect the two' with no implication of it being a boolean function. And 'disjoin' as a verb is even worse (it may not even be a recognized word).

The most accurate forms are:

> **Form the conjunction of A and B**

or

> **Form the disjunction of A and B**

or less academic sounding:

> **create 'A and B'**
>
> **create 'A or B'**

But informally, your suggested sentences get across the idea very accurately.

Comment: also, as my comment on the OQ, check with mathematics.SE, as there  is probably a standard turn of phrase in that particular environment (I have doubts about mine being standard for mathematics).

Comment: I’m not too big on the whole *conjoin/disjoin* idea myself, but one must recognize that the OED certainly has plenty on *disjoin* as a verb. So *conjoin* does have a mate. They make an odd couple whether together or singularly, though. Some sample defs: To undo the joining of; to put or keep asunder; to disunite, separate, sunder, part, sever. . . . To separate into parts or sections; to disjoint. To sunder, dissolve, break up (a state or condition of union); to undo, unfasten (a knot or tie). To separate or sever oneself from a state of union or attachment; to part, become separate. . . .

Answer (score 4):

*Connect*, plain and simple. You connect the clauses using *and* or *or*. Which is why they are called [logical connectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective).

> In logic, a *logical connective* (also called a *logical operator* or *a truth function*) is a symbol or word **used to connect** two or more sentences (of either a formal or a natural language) in a grammatically valid way[.]

Emphasis added.

Answer (score 0):

As Shyam observed, "and"ing can be described as combining.

A word for the act of "or"ing might be [disjunction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disjunction).

Comment: Ah yeah, and the act of "and"ing is conjunction...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Good point!

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing about the mathematical or computer operations, I think you're better off to say AND and OR, because your audience should know what those mean. If they don't, they can look them up. If you use some alternative word, your readers are likely to wonder, "Does he mean 'AND'? If he did, why didn't he just say 'AND'?" etc.

If you're looking for a general term that includes AND, OR, and NOT, I'd say "logical operators" or "logical operations". Again, that's the accepted term. As in, "The available logical operators in this language are ..."

If you're talking about common English, if you want to say, "I went to the barbershop AND to the grocery store" but not using the word "AND", that's an entirely different question, and this response is totally irrelevant.